# Is it possible to share connection pool between two applications in same server ind odp.net

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I have two applications in server.Their db user is same.Their connections strings are same

Is it possible to share connection pool between two applications.

What I want to do?For example If one application opens 10 connection and they are idle,the other application use these idle connections not open new one

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, each application would use it's own instantiation of the connection pool object and would not be able to share as you describe. You should manage each connection pool to draw down to the minimum number of persistent connections that are appropriate for each application when each app is idle.

You may be able to leverage Oracle's Universal Connection Pool ([see here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/intro.htm#BABDIDGD)) to achieve the effect you want, if the applications can share the same defined data source. Check the documentation to see if that would work for your at specific apps.